# I keep getting the same error whenever I try to create my recursion method

Tags: java

Well essentially, I created my recursive method and believed I finished it, yet I keep getting the same error no matter what I do! Can anyone tell me what I'm missing. The error is "The method eatTaco(Taco) in the type Taco is not applicable for the arguments (int)".

```
   //recursive method
    public static int eatTaco(Taco t) {
          if (t.getOunces() == 0) {
         System.out.println("Done");
    } 
        else {
    System.out.println("There are " + t.getOunces() + " of " + t.getType() + " taco remaining.");
        return eatTaco(t.getOunces() - 1);
    }

    }
```

Comment: I got it guys! Thank you for the help, it guided me in the right direction!!

Answer (score 1):

This method signature says that `eatTaco` takes a `Taco` object as its argument.

```
public static int eatTaco(Taco t)
```

But when you call it, you pass in an integer value.

```
return eatTaco(t.getOunces() - 1);
```

You need a way to subtract an ounce from the taco, *then* call `eatTaco` again. Something like this:

```
System.out.println("There are " + t.getOunces()...
t.setOunces(t.getOunces() - 1);
return eatTaco(t);
```

Comment: Hi! I did this and now the error i receive is in my method header and it says "This method must return a result of type int". Which I understand but I'm just stumped because of the way it's formatted.

Comment: I got the method definition to work, but now in my main when I want to call  it. it still tells me " The method eatTaco(Taco) in the type Taco is not applicable for the arguments (int)"

Comment: In the else block you are indeed returning an int. But in the if block you are not, and that is why you were getting the error "This method must return a result of type int". Just return 0 from the if block.

Answer (score 1):

The function `eatTaco(Taco t)` expects an argument with type taco. When you call the function recursively, you call `eatTaco(t.getOunces() - 1)`. This returns an int rather than a Taco, as the function expects.

Comment: ohhhh i see! Sorry I'm fairly new to java programming, so how would I be able to return the method as "Taco"

Comment: if there is a method in the Taco class to change the amount of ounces, something like t.setOunces(), you can run t.setOunces(t.getOunces() - 1), and then pass t into eatTaco.

Answer (score -1):

This line has error -

```
return eatTaco(t.getOunces() - 1);
```

Because eatTaco accepts Taco as an argument anf t.getOunces()-1 return an integer.

Maybe change it to `eatTaco(t.reduceOunces());`

and inside the Taco class -

```
 void reduceOunces(){ this.ounces - 1;}
```

Comment: You can't pass a void method call as an argument to another method. It's void.

Comment: I'm sorry but this didn't work as khelwood explained